# Use Jquery datepicker as month range picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I want to use jquery UI datepicker as month select picker. What is the code for it? Here I tried but it wasn't success

```
$('#startDateTotal').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'yy-MM ',
        maxDate: 0,
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
            $("#endDateTotal").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following css to it:

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
    display: none;
    }
```

This hides the calendar and is a hacky way of doing it, but it is the only way out.

Comment: already did. But the problem is when I select second month first selected month field cleared automatically

Comment: You mean that the value on second time is not shown correctly? You need to write a function for that, override the beforeShow method for the same.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following code helps you,

Visit http://jsfiddle.net/tmnasim/JLydp/

**html**

```
<label for="myDate">Date :</label>
<input name="myDate" class="monthYearPicker" />
```

**css**

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
display: none; }
```

**jquery**

```
$(function() {
$('.monthYearPicker').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'MM yy'
}).focus(function() {
    var thisCalendar = $(this);
    $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').detach();
    $('.ui-datepicker-close').click(function() {
        var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
        var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
        thisCalendar.datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
        });
    });
});
```